# How do I securely buy a domain from a private party?

Tags: domain-transferring

I have a domain I want.  I found the owners contact information, and negotiated a price.  Is there a domain brokerage service out there that would help me with the exchange.  I don't want to send off money, and never hear from him again, and I'm sure it's likewise.

I've found a lot of sites that carry collections of domains for sale, but I've already found mine, and contacted the owner.  I just want a service to facilitate the hand-off.

Has anyone used a service like this that they could recommend?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there anything I should know before trying to acquire a domain name from the current owner?](http://serverfault.com/questions/52868/is-there-anything-i-should-know-before-trying-to-acquire-a-domain-name-from-the-c)

Answer (score 6):

I've used escrow.com a few times to facilitate domain transfers for my organization.  You send escrow.com the money, do the domain transfer through your registrar of choice, and once you've confirmed the transfer is complete, they release the funds to the seller.  There is some added to cost to doing it this way however.

Comment: +1 Use a reputable escrow service.

Comment: Escrow is a great way to do this kind of thing. Too bad the fee is over 100% of the smaller transactions I'm looking at doing.